# Feynman Diagrams - Specific Questions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams

I have a very naive question concerning Feynman diagrams: If we consider the process $\pi^{+}\rightarrow \mu^{+}\nu_{\mu}$ via the weak interaction, then we get this Feynman Diagram according to Wikipedia:

[image]

Now, my question is the following: If I drew this diagram, is this also correct?

[image]

Or if I only exchanged the positions of $\mu^{+}$ and $\nu_{\mu}$? Personally, I'd say yes, but I just wanted to double-check.

Comment: What have you learnt that a Feynman diagram means? Also note that your drawn diagram doesn't make sense

Comment: Hi @NiharKarve, why doesn't my Feynman diagram make sense? I learned that a Feynman diagram is helpful tool for calculating things like cross-sections etc., but we haven't done these things yet.

Comment: An antimuon is an antiparticle, while a neutrino is a particle, so the arrows are the wrong way round

Comment: Ah, I see! But apart from the arrows - which are of course the wrong way around - it should be okay? Also, would the diagram still be valid if I exchanged *only* the positions of $\mu^{+}$ and $\nu_{\mu}$ in my own Feynman diagram?

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was what you want ask - yes, it would be valid: only the topology of the Feynman diagram is important

Comment: Thanks a lot! If you want, you can make that into an answer, and I'll be more than happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current diagram, as drawn, is incorrect as the antimuon $\mu^{+}$ and muon neutrino $\nu_{\mu}$ should have opposite arrows. However, if you were to reverse the arrows, the diagram would be correct as only the geometric topological properties of the Feynman diagram are relevant, and not the relative position of vertices.